# Reverse onClick Event onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to assign an onClick to an object that performs one action, then when the user clicks on the same object, the action is reversed?

```
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('#foo').css({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'white',
        'font-size': '44px'
    });
});
```

So clicking on #image will either add the changes to #foo or reverse changes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx5yH/804/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't manipulate with inline styles directly, this is not very flexible approach. Instead you want to toggle class that holds necessary styles:

```
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('#foo').toggleClass('active');
});
```

where the class `active` is defined like this:

```css
#foo.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 44px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sx5yH/812/

Answer (score 4):

Specifically in your case - it is better to assign a class to the object. Then you can use the jquery toggle functionality to add/remove the style.

CSS

```
#image.selected {
       background-color: red;
       color: white;
       font-size: 44px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('#image').toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: He wants to apply the `.selected` class to `#foo`, not to `#image`. Your answer was good before you changed that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gb0udnft/1/

You can use a boolean value to determine whether or not it's been clicked, then use a ternary statement to do whatever depending if it's true or false.

```
(boolean) ? true : false;
```

You could also use the innate JQuery toggle() function

http://jsfiddle.net/gb0udnft/2/

```
    $('#image').toggle(function() {
    // do whatever 
       }
      , function() {
       // do whatever
});
```

or use a css class back and forth by using .toggleClass(), .addClass(), or .removeClass()